# Hardhat Etherscan Unsupported Network Sepolia chain Id: 11155111

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, sepolia

I have configure my project with **nomiclabs hardhat-etherscan** and `hardhat.config.ts` with sepolia network as goerli network as high gas fees.

I could also deploy the contract with hardhat.config.ts but I am unable to verify the contract on sepolia test network.

Deployed Contract Address: [0x6Fc8481F93Ae4725DA1120BBEF6B1E593F7956c4](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x6Fc8481F93Ae4725DA1120BBEF6B1E593F7956c4)

Here's my `hardhat.config.ts`

```
 etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  },

if (process.env.NETWORK_SEPOLIA_URL !== undefined) {
  console.log("Using Sepolia network");

  config.networks!.testnet = {
    url: process.env.NETWORK_SEPOLIA_URL,
    accounts: [process.env.SEPOLIA_PRIVATE_KEY!],
  }
```

I am using command `hardhat verify --constructor-args config/ContractArguments.ts`

Here's ContractArguments.ts

```
import { utils } from "ethers";
import CollectionConfig from "./CollectionConfig";

// Update the following array if you change the constructor arguments...
const ContractArguments = [
  CollectionConfig.tokenName,
  CollectionConfig.tokenSymbol,
  utils.parseEther(CollectionConfig.whitelistSale.price.toString()),
  CollectionConfig.maxSupply,
  CollectionConfig.whitelistSale.maxMintAmountPerTx,
  CollectionConfig.hiddenMetadataUri,
] as const;

export default ContractArguments;
```

> Error: Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: Unsupported
> network ("sepolia", chainId: 11155111).

Comment: Hey,
Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar error, but updating @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan to the latest version worked for me.

```
npm update @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan
```

Comment: I am using @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan 3.1.7 version

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while verifying my contract using [hardhat-etherscan] so I updated the package using this command in the console >>> `npm update @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan`

This worked for me, you can give it a try too!

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, Sepolia is not supported by hardhat-etherscan

Comment: I know it's not supported but when you check hardhat documentation they've provided configuration for sepolia network. I have followed them as is but still it doesn't work.